# In Java, how does a post increment operator act in a return statement?

Tags: java, operators

Given the following code, will ixAdd do what you'd expect, i. e. return the value of ix before the increment, but increment the class member before leaving the function?

```
class myCounter {
    private int _ix = 1;

    public int ixAdd()
    {
        return _ix++;
    }
}
```

I wasn't quite sure if the usual rules for post / pre increment would also apply in return statements, when the program leaves the stack frame (or whatever it is in Java) of the function.

Comment: ehm.. you mean, like paste the code above in my editor and run it? I don't know, sorry. :-p I'll go get myself a cup of coffee...

Comment: voted for close... I thought the author could just close it immediately?

Comment: Hey, now I know why I didn't try: To get Jon Skeet's answer. It's actually more useful than the question.

Comment: @PT funny how it would have been easy to just try :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The key part is that a post increment/decrement happens *immediately* after the expression is evaluated. Not only does it happen before the return occurs - it happens before any later expressions are evaluated. For instance, suppose you wrote:

```
class myCounter {
    private int _ix = 1;

    public int ixAdd()
    {
        return _ix++ + giveMeZero();
    }

    public int giveMeZero()
    {
        System.out.println(_ix);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

That would print out the incremented result as well, because the increment happens before `giveMeZero()` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jon. As Paul Tomblin pointed out, typing the code in my editor instead of the post would have answered it, too. But now I got more out of it than I asked for.

Comment: @Jon:  For people coming from C to Java (which will be a lot of people), this is a good thing to point out.  As a long time Java user who first used C for a long, long time, I didn't know that Java defined how ++ works so much more clearly than C does.  I learned to avoid "clever" ++ use from C!

Comment: _Not only does it happen before the return occurs_  but return statement is not returning the incremented value if its a local variable. Your example shows a global variable.

Comment: @ernesto: It doesn't make any difference: the return statement returns the value of the expression, which will be the pre-increment value. That's the same whether it uses a local variable or a field. The field is used here to show that the `giveMeZero` method observes the incremented value.

Answer (score 16):

Well, let's look at the bytecode (use `javap -c <classname>` to see it yourself):

```
Compiled from "PostIncTest.java"
class myCounter extends java.lang.Object{
myCounter();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   iconst_1
   6:   putfield    #2; //Field _ix:I
   9:   return

public int ixAdd();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   dup
   2:   getfield    #2; //Field _ix:I
   5:   dup_x1
   6:   iconst_1
   7:   iadd
   8:   putfield    #2; //Field _ix:I
   11:  ireturn

}
```

As you can see, instructions 6 and 7 in `ixAdd()` handle the increment before the return. Therefore, as we would expect, the decrement operator does indeed have an effect when used in a return statement. Notice, however, that there is a `dup` instruction before these two appear; the incremented value is (of course) not reflected in the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the usual rules apply for post increment even on a return statement.  Basically, what it will do at a low level is store the return value into a register, then increment the class member, then return from the method.

You can see this in [a later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654715/in-java-how-does-a-post-increment-operator-act-in-a-return-statement/654741#654741) to this question that showed the byte code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

But don't do that, it is bad style to have side effects in expressions.

Comment: The side effect here is very much intended and I can't see it do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

It does return the value before the increment, and then increment _ix. Therefore the first time you call the method ixAdd on an instance of myCounter it will return 1, the second time it will return 2, and so on.