# What happen in method after return statement

Tags: java, variables, return

```
public class TestReturn {
     int i = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestReturn t = new TestReturn();

        System.out.println(t.test());
        System.out.println(t.i);
    }

    private int test() {
            return i++;
    }
}
```

output

```
0
1
```

My question is,

1. Since return value of test() is 0, i,e un-incremented, so when i print i why it is incremented. What i know is, `return` is the exit point of method but from this method i found that there is something happening after returning from method.

So how exactly return works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple.

When you do `return i++` `i` is initially 0. The `i++` is called the *post*-increment and as its name says `i` will be incremeneted *after*.

Although `i++` returns a value *before* incrementing, the method finishes this statement before heading back to `main`. A return won't abruptly stop this statement halfway(evaluating but not incrementing)

So you'll return 0, increment it, and then see 1 when calling `System.out.println(t.i);`.

---

Technically, the value of `i` is stored onto the stack, the class field is incremented, and then the copied-out values of `i` is returned.

Comment: So, Is execution of `i++` not part of method stack?

Comment: @Gaurav The increment of `i` is done inside and during the execution of the function, however the value returned hasn't yet been incremented.

Comment: @GauravGupta Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/654741/1424875). As you can see it will store the return value into a register, increment the field called `i`, and then return from that register.

Comment: +1 for pointing to the link. This is the point i wanted to know. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the return that's the problem here, it's your usage of the post-increment operator.

What happens with "return i++;" is that the value of i is returned, then the value is incremented. That's why you get 0 and 1 as the values.

Answer (score 0):

If u wanna return `1`, give `return ++i;`

`return i++;` will first return `i`, then increment it;

`i++` can be imagined as another function like (the syntax not applicable to java tough)-

```
preIncrementFunction(int &i){
   int j = *i;
   *i = *i+1;
   return j;
}
```

so, the value getting printed is the un-incremented value of `i` but the value of `i` has changed.

Comment: Again it creates same question in my mind, Is execution of `i++` doesn't occur in method's stack. AFAIK, method's stack is destroyed after return statement. But since i++ is executing after returning from method, then i++ must be executing somewhere else, what is that `somewhere`.

Comment: Yes `return` will terminate the `stack`. That's how the `++` operator works, here `i++` is implemented before `return` is executed fully but the value returned is previous value of `i` as per the `++` is given as `i++` or `++i`.
for more visualization see the edit.

Comment: In case of ++i we will get incremented value from the return statement, But, yes for rest part you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of actions in executing the statement `return i++;` is as follows.

1. Evaluate the expression `i++`.

   a. Take the value of `i`

   b. Increment the variable.
2. Return the value of the expression produced by step 1.

The evaluation of the expression is completed (including the increment) within the method call ... before the call returns.

> Since return value of test() is 0, i,e un-incremented, so when i print i why it is incremented.

As you can see from my explanation above, that is because `i` was incremented as part of the expression evaluation; step 1b.