# How does return i++ work?

Tags: stack, operators

This is a question about the ++ operator. It is a question that doesn't solve a problem but I believe that it would be very informative to know the answer. So, while StackOverflow is a source of information, I would like to append the available knowledge here!

So, the problem:

```
int i = 0;

int getNextInt(){

    return i++;
}
```

This is it. The question is how the ++ operator is implemented in the function call stack and where the increment actually happens when we call that function in our code.

I am really wondering a long time!

Comment: Remove the "language-agnostic" tag and include a relevant language tag - because `++` is *far* from being "language-agnostic".

Comment: You can find the answer to your question, applyed to Java, here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654715/in-java-how-does-a-post-increment-operator-act-in-a-return-statement

Answer (score 2):

It happens after the function returns it's value. In this case, it returns 0 and then increments the variable, so the next time it will return 1

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the compiler actually does with regard to the stack, but if it chose to, the compiler could easily rearrange it to this:

```
int getNextInt() {
    int temp = i;
    i++;
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`i++` is the same as saying `i = i+1`

It is just a shorthand way of redefining the variable.