# Why is post increment operator in a return statement act different from expected in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I see this post: [In Java, how does a post increment operator act in a return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654715/in-java-how-does-a-post-increment-operator-act-in-a-return-statement)

And the conclusion is: **a post increment/decrement happens immediately after the expression is evaluated. Not only does it happen before the return occurs - it happens before any later expressions are evaluated.**

I tried the sample code in the post like below in Eclipse:

```
class myCounter {
    private int _ix = 1;

    public int ixAdd() {
        return _ix++ + giveMeZero();
    }

    public int giveMeZero()
    {
        System.out.println(_ix);
        return 0;
    }
}

public class mytest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myCounter m = new myCounter();
        System.out.println(m.ixAdd());
    }
}
```

and the result is:

```
2

1
```

It shows that `_ix` is incremented to `2` in `giveMeZero()` as expected. But `ixAdd()` is still returning `1`.

Why is this happening? Isn't it against what [In Java, how does a post increment operator act in a return statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654715/in-java-how-does-a-post-increment-operator-act-in-a-return-statement) is all about?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the post increment operator evaluates to the original value before the increment is performed.

This means that e.g.

```
int a = i++;
```

is similar to doing:

```
int a = i;
i = i + 1;
```

That is, `a` receives the original value of `i` and after that, `i` is incremented.

When used in a return statement, there's no difference, it evaluates to the value before the increment.

```
return _ix++ + giveMeZero();
```

would be similar to:

```
int temp = _ix;
_ix = _ix + 1;

return temp + giveMeZero();
```

Comment: to sum up: you have postincremented the value of _ix but you haven assigned this value to _ix

Answer (score 2):

Think about the compiler evaluating each part of that `return` statement on at a time:

```
 return _ix++ + giveMeZero();
```

Is the same as:

```
int tmp1 = _ix++;
int tmp2 = giveMeZero();
return tmp1 + tmp2;
```

So by the time `giveMeZero` is evaluated, `_ix` has already been incremented.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `_ix++ + giveMeZero();` first return then add 1 to `_ix`.

if you do `++_ix` then it is OK

**Note:**  `++` if first occur it means that firs add one and then do the operation, if occur after then it means that first do that operation then add one